# ORA-017 errors in entity framework

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-4

I Have two Table(SuperType and Subtype)

SUperType:SWHEADER and Subtype=SW799 
[image]

[image]

now in EF:
[image]:

and my DTO:

parnet:
[image]

child:
[image]

in inserting dont any problem but when get(select) accured error:ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression

tanx a lot.

Comment: Because you don't create corretc relationship.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use long data types in unions, the sql generated by the entity framework provider uses unions for inheritance and multiple includes

[Oracle Union Restrictions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm)